# Does "Enable Robust Exception Information" need to be disabled for cferror to work?

Tags: exception, coldfusion

I am working on some old Coldfusion sites using the cferror tag in an Application.cfm to redirect errors (exception and request types).  The strange thing is, the sites are hosted on two different shared hosts, one of the shared hosts has "Robust Exception Information" enabled and the other disabled.  The cferror tag redirects errors properly when the site is hosted on the host with robust info disabled, but not when its enabled....does having robust information enabled somehow cause cferror to be ignored, or is something stranger going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, no. I have a live site running with robust exception information turned off, and the `<cferror>` tag executes properly.

Comment: What I am asking about is actually the opposite; does cferror execute when robust exception information is ON.  I could sort of see the logic if this was the case (as in if you are enabling something to see errors, cferror would get in the way of it), but I can't find any documentation of this relationship.

Comment: ahh, yes. not a helpful answer

Comment: That's okay.  Is there anyway you can test it out by switching the setting?  I can't change the settings in my current situation because its a clients live host.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't, as I'm also running on a live host.